# Console.ReadLine() alternative

Tags: c#, console, key

I have the following console application:

```
private static bool run = false;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int choice = 0;  

    while (!run) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t Press '1', '2' or '3' to continue");

        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t you pressed 1");
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t you pressed 2");
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t you pressed 3");
                }
            default:
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t Invalid key");
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However, with this code:

```
choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I wish to have it so that when the user pressed the 1 key or 2 or 3, the appropriate code is executed straight away, as opposed to having to press the enter key once you've pressed the desired key. What are some alternatives?

Any help/guidance/tips is greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about [`ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx) then?

Comment: could you give an example of how I could use ReadKey with this line choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); Thanks

Comment: @Ari: `ReadKey` returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo`, you can directly switch on its `Key` without doing any parsing to integer. If you really must parse something you can parse the `KeyChar`...

Comment: @Ari: ...but then again, you could directly switch on the char as well.

Comment: @Ari: I usually don't want to "railroad" my answers, there are various methods to use `ReadKey` and i am in no position to tell people which they *should* use. I think the comments are enough in terms of suggestions for those who have no idea, also there's the documentation that i linked to which gives an example as well.